# CMDH and CoAP both define retry policies, which should be used?

Tags: coap, onem2m

When CMDH processing is in use to retry communications between CSEs, **and** that communication link uses CoAP (which defines its own retry logic), which retry policy should be used: CMDH or CoAP?

Answer (score 0):

CMDH processing - level retries happens on a higher layer than the transport protocol's retransmission. This is the same as with any transport protocol, e.g. with TCP/IP retransmissions. Those can actually be quite dynamic, depending also on various external factors (network defaults, congestion, etc).

CMDH retries are application-level settings and should be set to a higher value, but this depends on the use case, e.g. when does it actually still make sense to process an old event.